# Reusing old laptop parts in new laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, cpu, motherboard

I have an old HCL ME P38 pdc laptop which is dead now.

It had

- CPU: 478 pin Socket p based supported processor(dual core)
- core logic or video controller: NVIDIA nforce MCP79MVL (with inbuilt GeForce 8200M G) single chip solution
- storage: 320 GB 2.5" SATA or SATA II hdd up to 720 rpm
- memory: 4GB DDR2 SD-RAM (SO-DIMM package)

As mentioned laptop is dead because

1. The port in the motherboard where we plug in the charger & charge the laptop is burnt(I got the burning smell and blinking of screen)
2. The battery is dead
3. Dvd drive is also dead

Now I want to know what must I do to use the parts such as CPU, graphics card, HDD, RAM with my new laptop

1. I know HDD can be used with enclosures and ram can be reused but enclosure cost too much (here in india) and I can't reuse the RAM as my new laptop uses DDR3 and old one used DDR2
   Please help?
2. Also can anyone tell what does 478 pin socket p based supported processor(dual core) means
3. Please tell which motherboard does it uses and what can I do anything other than replacing motherboard?
4. I think that the graphics card is embedded in it can it be used anywherebecause it just rests at my house

Please help as I have searched through net and this product is obsolete

Comment: There is not a single part of that laptop that is worth keeping except perhaps the HDD.  You will require a enclosure to place it in because its not likely worth actually using as your system drive.  The memory cannot be used its basically worthless. All current equipment sold today is DDR3.  Additionally the CPU is integrated into the motherboard and cannot be removed by you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Pretty much everything in your old laptop is obsolete
2. Any attempt in 'reusing' parts from your old laptop in a 'new' laptop will result in warranty for the new laptop being void.
3. You can't say I don't want a CPU or a hard drive for the new laptop.

You're better off recycling the old laptop and get a new one. Any effort in trying to save costs will result in more overheads and expenses.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing reusable is the HDD, everything else is unusable because it's either outdated or intergraded into the motherboard. Laptops can't be upgraded like desktops so your stuck with your GPU and CPU until you upgrade.